# pumpkins turning white and dying on the vine

Tags: diagnosis, pumpkins

My pumpkins are dying.  They get to be about 5 inched around and then they turn white and die.  Why?

Comment: Are the leaves turning white as well? Is this mildew or rot?

Comment: What you need to do is identify if this is a fungi or a disease.

Comment: A picture of the situation would be helpful for diagnosis.

Comment: Please send a picture or two.  One of the entire plant and one up close.  There are pumpkins that are white.  Really need a picture, thanks, Valerie  Oh also tell us where you live, what you have done for the plant such as fertilizer and your watering habits.

Comment: is it the cultivar